# File and folder mirroring required, to work on multiple systems

Tags: hard-drive, backup, external-hard-drive, mirroring, duplicate

I am a graphic designer and I work on multiple systems, an imac at my office, and a laptop at home. i generally work on one system and then continue the work on other system, and more frequently i need the files, even the ones i worked on say one month or 6 months back. Till now i have been using an external drive to do all my work on, and then carry the external drive to whichever system i like and i would get all the files with me anywhere and anytime.

But recently, my external hard drive crashed, and i didnt have any backup (so irresponsible of me), and lost all my files. but thats not the issue. i guess you learn from your mistakes.

I am searching for a solution, lets say i am working on my imac, all the files and folders are automatically duplicated (mirrored) to an external drive, so that i can carry that external drive anywhere to work on without fearing because now i would have two local copies of the same files. I am not looking for a backup solution, coz i am using time-machine for backup (after my mistake).

i was searching for this solution in the internet and i came accross RAID, but i dont know if thats what i am looking for. any help would be much appreciated and if there is any other better option, please share.

Or it can be something like i am directly working on my external drive and the files are automatically backed up on my imac.

Answer (score 1):

RAID needs more than one disk, so you will be lugging around an enclosure with at least
two disks in it, which will be much too heavy and complicated.

I suggest instead using an online service, maybe more than one, while always keeping
local backups on all your computers.

Many online services offer quite large disk space in the cloud.
Some such services are : Microsoft OneDrive, Dropbox, Google Drive, SpiderOak,
Mega. These are the best-known, but others do exist.